# Can you type subscript on signs in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In some of Iskall's videos, he adds a TM in subscript on signs for fun.  Is this possible in vanilla Minecraft, or is this done with a mod?

Answer (score 6):

ᵧₑₛ, ᵢₜ'ₛ ₚₒₛₛᵢ₆ₗₑ, ₆ᵤₜ ᵢₜ ᵥᵥₒₙ'ₜ ₗₒₒₖ ₚₑᵣբₑ꜀ₜ. ᵀʰᶦˢ ᶦˢ ʲᵘˢᵗ ᵁⁿᶦᶜᵒᵈᵉ ᵗʳᶦᶜᵏᵉʳʸ, ⁿᵒᵗ ᵃᶜᵗᵘᵃˡ ᶠᵒʳᵐᵃᵗᵗᶦⁿᵍ.

I used this tool: https://lingojam.com/SubscriptGenerator

Here you can see all the JSON formatting options: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format
The normal text formattings are colour, font, bold, italics, underlined and strikethrough.